80s film about Military academy
I'm looking for a movie from the 80's. I don't remember it's name.
Two naughty high school boys are sent to a military school. One of them was a stutterer. They did some jokes including putting doves in the manager's draw and ordered workers to dig in the wrong place and the pipeline started to blow and so on.
In the military school they continued with their jokes. The son of the military school's manager stolen a watch and the manager accused one of the naughty boys. Afterwards, the son of the manager admitted the crime. The stutterer guy fell in love with his lady commander.
The movie is ended with fireworks that one of the boys made them explode. Please let me know that you know the movie.

This is Combat Academy (AKA Combat High) from 1986.

"Police Academy"-style comedy set in a military school. Two errant high-school students are ordered by a judge to spend a year at a prestigious military academy, where one of the cadets finds out who is responsible for a spate of midnight thefts.

One of the 2 guys stutters, and the principal's son who steals the watch is actually George Clooney in his film debut! The other scenes you described are there too, some of which (like the pipe bursting) you can see in the trailer:



